# how to get running total by month

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying populate a graph and my Model looks like this

```
public class Transaction : BaseEntity
{
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public double TransactionAmount { get; set; }
}
public enum TransactionType{
    Deposit = 0,
    Withdraw = 1
}
```

i populated this model with sample data of first 2 months of 2018.

```
    b.HasData(new
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                TransactionAmount = 3334.38,
                TransactionDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-2).Year, 1, 20),
                TransactionType = TransactionType.Deposit
            });
            b.HasData(new
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                TransactionAmount = -3334.38,
                TransactionDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-2).Year, 1, 21),
                TransactionType = TransactionType.Withdraw

            });
            b.HasData(new
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                TransactionAmount = 1000.23,
                TransactionDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-2).Year, 1, 25),
                TransactionType = TransactionType.Deposit
            });
            b.HasData(new
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                TransactionAmount = 1008.18,
                TransactionDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-2).Year, 4, 10),
                TransactionType = TransactionType.Deposit
            });
            b.HasData(new
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                TransactionAmount = -34.10,
                TransactionDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-2).Year, 4, 19),
                TransactionType = TransactionType.Withdraw
            });
```

I am trying to get a result that what was the balance at end of each month.

for example in

2018    Jan   1000.23
        April 1974.23 (1000.23 from January + 974.0 from April)

but what i am getting is

Jan 1000.23
   April 974.0

basically it is adding all the values in each month individually.

```
 var data = from t in transactions
                   group t by new { t.TransactionDate.Year, t.TransactionDate.Month } into g
                   select new
                   {
                       //Balance = g.Select(i =>
                       //{
                       //    currentTotal += g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount);
                       //    return new
                       //    {
                       //        //Date = i.TransactionDate,
                       //        //Amount = i.TransactionAmount,
                       //        currentTotal
                       //    };
                       //}),
                       Balance = g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount),
                       g.First().TransactionDate.Month,
                       g.First().TransactionDate.Year
                   };
        var yearlyGroups = data.OrderBy(x => x.Month).GroupBy(x => x.Year);
        var lastTwoYearsSortedByMonth = yearlyGroups.OrderBy(x => x.Key).TakeLast(2);
```

As you can see in the code above i tried something to get the running total. but not working.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you then need to `.Aggregate()` your results

Comment: .Aggregate is a LINQ function ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what's the query syntax equivalent and I'm typing from my phone, sorry

Comment: Yes trying this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have misled you with my suggestion. I couldn't come up with an elegant enough solution that would've used `.Aggregate()`.

```cs
    var runningBalance = 0.0;
    var data = transactions.GroupBy(t => new { t.TransactionDate.Year, t.TransactionDate.Month })
        .OrderBy(d => d.Key.Year)
        .ThenBy(dd => dd.Key.Month)
        .Select((g) => new
        {
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            Month = g.Key.Month,
            Balance = g.Sum(i => i.TransactionAmount),
            RunningBalance = (runningBalance = (runningBalance + g.Sum(i => i.TransactionAmount)))
        });
```

Comment: awsome it worked for me. Just one minor change, i ordered by Year and then by month. Not sure if it makes any difference. overall it worked. Thankyou !!!!

Comment: no difference as far as LINQ is concerned. You just need to ensure correct order before you start calculating your totals. I'll update the answer to match your sorting